# Is there a fixed-width space character that is not subject to expansion in a justified paragraph?

Tags: html

Justified paragraphs expand inter-word spacing, but I expected `&nbsp;` to be unaffected by this expansion. Unfortunately, it *is* affected, and so I need to find an unaffected space character (preferably one with the same width as an ordinary space in an ordinary left-justified paragraph). Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the reason for needed a character? Just wondering.

Comment: Abbreviations like "i. e." and "e. g." look very ugly when the space is expanded.

Comment: there's no space in i.e. and e.g.

Comment: @76987 That’s because there isn’t supposed to be a space there at all. Simply “i.e.” & “e.g.”.

Comment: @Sebas Unfortunately, there *is* a space in old texts that use those abbreviations. That's what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Unfortunately, there *is* a space in old texts that use those abbreviations. That's what I'm trying to replicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just add a character such as `.` and make it invisible.

It works. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KM4Vz/)

It is not parsed as whitespace, since it is technically a character that just isn't visible.

For a cleaner method, you could insert the character via the `:after` pseudo element..

```
span:after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SHMTm/)

Comment: Removing that character/span doesn’t change appearance at all. So what’s the point? There’s also no single-width space present.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Actually yes, there is a space present in both example! Look at it closely.. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltftb.png .. that is specifically what the OP wants.

Comment: Not on Chrome 30, Chrome 32, FF 24, or Safari 6 (all on OS X 10.8). https://i.imgur.com/dOTWXlu.png

Comment: It does on Windows Chrome/FF/IE. What about the `span`? That should definitely work.

Comment: Yes, the span does work. For some reason I thought it didn’t, but maybe was looking at the first one again.

Comment: Also, Unicode 0x01 is the SOH, or start of heading character. Doesn’t really make sense to try and use it as a space. I’m not sure why you denote it as “blank”. This is probably related to why it doesn’t reliably work.

Comment: @JoshC I don't see any space. I've repeated it a few times to see if the space grows, but it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/3jX6E/1/

Comment: @76987 You're right. AndewMarshall pointed that out above. Don't use that method.

Comment: What happens when you copy/paste this?

Comment: Is this screen reader friendly?

Answer (score 8):

The rendering of space characters other than SPACE and NO-BREAK SPACE is not defined in HTML specifications. In practice, various [fixed-width spaces](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) can be used, and they are not expanded in justification (effectively, they are treated as graphic characters, just with empty glyphs). The one that most closely matches a normal space in width is FOUR-PER-EM SPACE, `&#x2005;`, but from the comments, it seems that you would rather want to use THIN SPACE or SIX-PER-EM SPACE.

Previously, browsers used to treat NO-BREAK SPACE as non-expansible, and some may still do, but for some odd reason, most browsers have abandoned this sensible idea. There is no guarantee that they won’t do the same to fixed-width space.

Apart from the theoretical point and the risk mentioned, fixed-width spaces suffer from font problems and breakability. The font problems mainly apply to old versions of IE, and the breakability (i.e., fixed-width spaces are treated as allowing a line break after them) could be addressed by using NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE if its width suits you and you take the risk with the font issue.

So it is probably best to do the spacing in CSS, even though it means a bit more work. For e.g. “e.g.” with spacing after the first period, you would need to decide whether it should be “e.g.” or “e. g.” at the character level. In the former case, just wrap the first period in a `span` and set `padding-right` on it. In the latter case, you could e.g. use `e.<span class=thin>&nbsp;</span>g.` and set the width of the `span` to something sufficiently small (using `display: inline-block` and a `width` setting).

Answer (score 1):

Unicode offers several [spacing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode). Of use here is probably the [thin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_Space), (Unicode 0x2009, `&thinsp;` in HTML) which is smaller than, but close to, a regular space. [See it working on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHMTm/1/).

You may also be interested in the related Unicode 0x202F which is the non-breaking version of thin space.

The benefit of this over the hidden character method is that the whitespace actually still exists in the source, and thus will be read as such by a screen reader (whereas the hidden character will be wholly ignored).